# How will i add an option under customizer woocommerce section?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

[image: https://prnt.sc/m9tiah]

What is the customizer section name? I want to add a field option under customizer woocommerce section. Or how will I add a field under woocommerce option? Can someone help me with that?

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'woocommerce_secction_name' , array(
        'title'    => __( 'My Section Name', 'starter' ),
        'priority' => 30
    ) );   

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'starter_new_setting_name' , array(
        'default'   => '#000000',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Header Color', 'starter' ),
        'section'  => 'woocommerce_secction_name',
        'settings' => 'starter_new_setting_name',
    ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add section to WooCommerce Panel
$wp_customize->add_section( 'SECTION_NAME',
  array(
    'title'      => __( 'SECTION TITLE'),
    'panel'      => 'woocommerce',
    'capability' => '',
    'priority'   => 500,
  )
);
```

The important part is the panel name as you can see selecting woocommerce it will add to the woocomerce panel